# Where is LIRC 36 kHz modulation function?

Tags: linux, lirc

I'd like to modify LIRC to output non-modulated signal (without 36-39 kHz modulation). I'm looking at irsend.c, but fail to see the hardware control code. It must have been somewhere in lirc main files. Any hints?

Comment: Oh, it must be lirc driver... irsend just writes to a device. No way I can go that deep...

Comment: Actually, traditional parallel port LIRC did do modulation on the PC itself. That's because LIRC hardware was originally an IR LED and a bunch of resistors hanging off the parallel/printer port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the solution was already in the driver. The modified driver for raspberry pi (lirc_rpi) takes a few parameters, among them ***softcarrier***.
So if you do:

```
sudo modprobe lirc_rpi softcarrier=0
```

the carrier wave will be eliminated.